# Question ban too easy

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I have 7 questions, 2 are downvoted (don't know why) and 5 are upvoted.

The last question was closed for being too broad (which is not, it asks how I can do a particular thing with MongoDB that just didn't got answered).

My rep is 226.

When would be a good time for the site's administration to rethink banning to actually ban people that deserve to get banned?

Most of the people I know ask in google groups or Quora just because normal answers get downvoted and getting banned while being professionals.

Comment: Note that the question ban is *purely* algorithmic.  The moderators on the site have no part in making it turn on or off.

Comment: how many of your questions are deleted, what is their score?

Comment: ...you can see your recent deleted questions here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/154794 If needed, moderators can find older deleted questions

Comment: I have no deleted recent questions. It is algorithmic for sure, I am proposing to make the algorithm less strict.

Comment: You have 3 deleted questions, 2 of which are in the negative. This is nothing more than an (educated) guess, but I think you are right on the q-ban threshold. A couple of upvotes on your visible questions, or a good answer is probably all you need to get unbanned.

Answer (score 5):

> The last question was closed for being too broad (which is not, it asks how I can do a particular thing with MongoDB that just didn't got answered).

Maybe you have a marginal question there that can be improved. Questions are closed so that they can be either improved or deleted, not necessarily just deleted.

That question's title says:

```
Best way to intersect a big set with another big set from a database
```

And it was closed as "too broad."

Maybe you should edit the title to be more clear that you're specifically asking about 2 arrays in MongoDB. Using bullets to note your expected options might help as well.

You're likely not banned permanently, they just want you to fix your initial question, if you can. I'm sure if you fix it, you'll be able to ask more questions very soon.

> When would be a good time for the site's administration to rethink?

While I don't intend to speak for Stackoverflow or the Programmer's community (I'm fairly new to Programmers) I believe we're trying to get to where we reopen more questions and get more questions answered without sacrificing quality.

So let's focus on getting your question improved so it can be reopened.

Comment: First we are missing a few things in all stack exchange sites. If a question doesn't have an answer in a day or two it is closed as too broad or some other reason category. That is simply not true and this question is an example of a problem that is very difficult (and is not 100% percent about Mongo that is why I didn't put it in the title). So if you leave these questions open someone at some point may come up with something and find it on google and answer it. The mentality of letting only super specific easily solvable questions only is hurting the community.

Comment: @arisalexis " If a question doesn't have an answer in a day or two it is closed as too broad or some other reason category."  I think you are wrong, there is a common cause between getting no answers (or only bad one) and getting closed: being unfit for the SE site.

Comment: @AProgrammer so we are excluding the possibility that hard questions that can have a low number of people that can answer them are delayed because these people didn't happen to be on the site on this day and the programmers xchange site is a bit lower on traffic than SO. It is absolute that all good programmers are online and everybody can answer difficult expert questions so if (no_answer) then question==bad. I totally disagree.

Comment: let me elaborate some more. Since the question is specific in the form how to do this with this software (A) and it has no answer in the form of it is not possible/it is possible with this solution (B) then it must have some SE site that is adequeate. So instead of closing maybe it's better to move it.

Comment: @arisalexis I strongly suggest you spend your energy on improving the question so that it can be reopened on the site, instead of adding more here. I don't have the energy or specific knowledge to improve it for you, otherwise I would. I'm cheering for you to cooperate with the site.

Comment: Don't ever ask for *best* in a question title. It may invite opinion. Good answers will automatically float to the top because of upvotes.